# How do you say "none available"?

Tags: translation, word-requests

How do you say "none available"? As in: "There is none available" (without the "there is". Or not.).

Comment: I saw a lot of signs saying 口罩无货 in Beijing recently (= facemasks, no product), so I think 无货 or 没有货 works.

Comment: Thank you! Nicely observed.

Comment: Hello, (1) we generally don't do translation requests unless you show some effort, and (2) please do not request words in Simplified Chinese (or Traditional Chinese, for that matter) - you should familiarise yourself with online converters if you want the text to be in the other script (Google Translate offers such a service). The tags [tag:simplified-chinese] and [tag:traditional-chinese] are for discussion about character forms and orthography, not for requesting that an answer be in Simplified Chinese or Traditional Chinese.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In this context )There is none available .= 沒了 = 沒貨 = 沒提供

Is the seat available ? No,it is not available. = 座位有人。 = 有人。

I'm not available at the moment = 我現在沒空。

The book is available from the bookshops.= 這本書可以從書店買到